# Best way to coordinate atomic transactions between different business services in .NET Core / EF Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say you have a UsersService, a TenantsService, and a TenantUserRolesService.

Each of these services has a "create" method to create their entity and has the same DbContext dependency injected, except for UsersService which has the Identity UserManager class injected.

Your goal is to provide an API endpoint that lets a new tenant register which creates a User, a Tenant, and a TenantUserRole entity. TenantUserRole is created last and is an associative entity with foreign keys to the newly created User, the newly created Tenant, and the "Owner" Role.

What's the best way to create an atomic transaction between these 3 services, so that if a single create fails, everything is rolled back and the DB is not in a broken state where there are tenants with no users or users with no tenants, etc.

I have looked at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions, but I can't figure out if there is a way to use those methods between different service classes.

The only way I can think of is to take an imperative approach and manually check the result of each create, and if there is an error then use the same entity service to delete the recently created entity.

I'm hoping there is someone who is a bit more knowledgeable on the subject that can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: If all services use the same underlying database context, you can just open up a transaction on it, run all three services, and then complete the transaction. This is because database contexts are request scoped, so all services will be able to use the same instance.

Comment: @poke Thanks! It didn't click to me that db contexts are request scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building RESTFul services, please bear in mind that REST services by definition are stateless, and they should not participate in a transactional boundary that spans more than one service.

Your services look like nanoservices. Your data is highly correlated so the way you've broken down your services feels very artificial. What if your application needs to display a list of all Tenants? Have you considered the performance implications and complexity of implementing HATEOUS?

My first suggestion would be to remodel your services. User Roles, User and arguably Tenant the way you've defined it should be in a single API. They're all related to a user and you've also indicated they all share the same `dbContext`. If this is not possible, the way architects solve the problem that you're trying to solve is through a concept of **Eventual Consistency**, i.e. synchronize the User, Tenant and User Role stores through some kind of background synchronization process.

Please do not be tempted to wrap your call to 3 APIs around a single transaction. Not only is this completely anti-REST, but chances are you don't need 3 APIs if they're all sharing the same database.

Answer (score 0):

If your transaction extend across service boundaries that is so called [Transactional integration antipattern](https://arnon.me/2010/09/soa-antipattern-transactional-integration/).

One way to coupe with that issue is to use external orchestration service (for example [Camunda](https://camunda.com/)). It's responsibility would be to handle business flow and do some compensation actions on failure.
It wouldn't be totally "transactional" - ACID properties would be achieved by compensations.

You can create that service by yourself. It's responsibility would be to manage that specific workflow.